# "Use of undeclared identifier 'PFUser'" in Parse

Tags: objective-c, xcode, parse-platform, mbaas, pfuser

I'm getting this error:

> Use of undeclared identifier 'PFUser'

With my application that has been integrated with Parse. It's worked before, and it worked perfectly. I found the error in this line of code:

```
[PFUser logInWithUsernameInBackground:_loginUsernameField.text password:_loginPasswordField.text block:^(PFUser *user, NSError *error) {
```

I've tried to insert all the frameworks all over again. So I removed all the frameworks and inserted all the frameworks listed below from Parse's official source.

```
     - Accounts.framework, AudioToolbox.framework, CFNetwork.framework,
       CoreGraphics.framework, CoreLocation.framework, libz.dylib,
       MobileCoreServices.framework, QuartzCore.framework, Security.framework,
       Social.framework, StoreKit.framework, SystemConfiguration.framework,
       Parse.framework, Bolts.framework, ParseFacebookUtils.framework
```

And again, there is only a single error, so I think there is an issue with 'PFUser.' 
If anybody has any suggestions, or maybe even a solution! That would really help me, and I'd appreciate it very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you import the framework at the top of the file:

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
```